# Split and non-latin strings in Python 2.X

Tags: python, utf-8, split

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
my_str = u'Строка ^ с ^ разделителями!' # Russian letters
print my_str.replace(' ', '')
print my_str.replace(' ', '').split('^')
```

Result:

```
Строка^с^разделителями!
[u'\u0421\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430 ', u' \u0441 ', u' \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044f\u043c\u0438!']
```

Please, help. How can I show 'normal' strings after splitting?

P.S.
File-script encoding is utf8

Comment: The primary Cyrillic block is 0x400-0x4ff. Printing a list prints the `repr` of the items, which for `unicode` objects shows the code point form (i.e. `\u####`) for non-ASCII codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These *are* normal strings, you're just seeing their internal representation (because you're not printing a string, you're printing a list in the second example). Do

```
for s in my_str.replace(' ', '').split('^'):
    print s
```

and you'll see. Conversely, try

```
print repr(my_str.replace(' ', ''))
```

and see what happens then.